# forked child process in node.js throws channel closed error on a post/put API call

Tags: node.js

I have a script file in Node js with a function that recursively calls itself after sometime outs.

This function sends out a "message" to which parent is listening.

This parent is nothing but a REST api with basic CRUD operations.

In this file, this is what forking part looks like:

```
var myBgTask = require('child_process').fork('./server/api/thing/bgTask.js', [], { execArgv: ['--debug=5859']});
myBgTask.on('message', function(data){
  //DO SOMETHING
})
```

Now, when from my angular code, I make a request to update the database, somehow the child process gets interrupted and throws Channel closed error at this line:

```
process.send({
    name: randomThing,
    readByUser: false 
   }, function(err){
    console.log("error", err)
    if(!err)
         setTimeout(autoCreate, randomNumb * 1000);

   });
```

and thus my server stops and I never am able to make http `post`/`put` calls.

Strange part is that it throws error only when I am making `post` or `put` calls and never with `get` calls.

I have been trying to debug this but have not been able to find out what the problem is. Can I get some help here on this?

Comment: angular code is front-end? IPC won't really work between a browser running on machine A and your server running on machine B, right?